# Inverse power-of-two in binary representation - how to calculate quickly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

how do I solve the equation $2^k = xn$ where $n$ and $k$ are known integers and $x$ is unknown integer? Is there some faster way than euclidean algorithm for division?

(In the case it is not solveable in integers, I want to maximize the length of the trail of 0s following the most significant $1$ digit of $xn$)

Comment: If $k$, $x$ and $n$ are integers, then $n$ and $x$ are both integral powers of $2$.  In this case, just subtract.  I don't think that's what you want.  Otherwise, you can just take logs (or, equivalently, work with the length of $n$ and $x$ in binary).

Comment: By hand or by computer ? Binary or decimal ? How many digits ?

Comment: Michael: Yep. Therefore I added the "in case not solveable in integers". 

Yves Daoust: Preferrably by computer and as fast as possible in hardware. Length.. typically $k\in[16,32]$ I think.

Comment: Yes logs is an interesting approach, maybe I can approximate it well in hardware somehow...